# Symfony: hydrate a form with entities saved in session (doctrine proxies)

Tags: php, forms, symfony, session, doctrine-orm

I am using symfony2 and doctrine2.
I have a function that performs a lot of calculations. The first screen displays the result and the second one displays a form to modify the results.
In order not to recalculate and requery the database, I am saving the first results in a session variable to pass them to the next screen, and I retrieve them there.
Now, I want to hydrate a form with the element retrieved from the session and I get the following error:

```
Entities passed to the choice field must be managed. Maybe persist them in the entity manager?
```

which I understand is triggered cause the entities retrieved from the session are not actual entities but proxies (object(Proxies__CG__\AppBundle\Entity\MarketPlace\Product)[512])

Can I not hydrate a form from data saved in the session ? How can I solve my problem ?

I have the following controller code:

```
/**
 * @Route("/planning_order", name="planning_order")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 * @Template(":MarketPlace/Order:planning_order.html.twig")
 * @param Request $request
 * @return array
 */
public function planningOrderAction(Request $request)
{
    $formManager = $this->get('form_manager');
    $orderManager = $this->get('order_manager');
    $order = new Order();

    $products = $this->get('session')->get('products');

    if (!$products)
    {
        $formManager->addError("Aucun planning de production n'a été trouvé. Veuillez en sélectionner pour générer des commandes.");
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('display_plannings', array('includeAssociates' => true)));
    }

    $placePlanningOrderForm = $orderManager->getPlacePlanningOrderForm($products, $order);

    return array('place_planning_order_form' => $placePlanningOrderForm->createView());
}
```

My form is generated like this :

```
/**
 * @param array $products
 * @param Order $order
 * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form|\Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface
 */
public function getPlacePlanningOrderForm(Array $products, Order $order)
{

    foreach ($products as $productData)
    {
        /** @var $product Product */
        $product = $productData['product'];
        $orderDetail = new OrderDetail();
        $orderDetail->setProduct($product);
        $order->addOrderDetail($orderDetail);
    }

    $placePlanningOrderForm = $this->formManager->createForm(
        new PlacePlanningOrderType(),
        $order,
        'POST',
        'planning_order'
    );

    return $placePlanningOrderForm;
}
```

and my form is the following:

```
    $builder
        ->add('product', 'genemu_jqueryselect2_entity', array(
                'label' => 'Produit',
                'class' => 'AppBundle:MarketPlace\Product'
            ))
        ->add('quantity', 'text', array('label' => 'Quantité à commander'))
    ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It mean that `UnitOfWork` knows nothing about entities you got them from a session. To get Entity in `MANAGED` state you should persist, refresh or find it (so Doctrine will start watch on this entity). So I suggest you to save not an objects, but IDs in your session and then just find all the Products with `id IN(array of IDs from session)`.

Comment: hmm, that's unfortunate we can't revert back from a proxy to an actual entity. I'll go with your solution then. thanks!